# How to evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{(2\sin x+\sec x)^4}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

I tried a lot but I am not able to get a start.

Can anyone give me the start of this question
$$
\int\frac{dx}{(2\sin x+\sec x)^4} \ ?
$$

Answer (score 2):

One may start with the change of variable
$$
t=\tan x,\quad \cos (2x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\quad \sin (2x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \quad dx=\frac1{1+t^2}\:dt,
$$
giving
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{(2\sin x+\sec x)^4}&=\int\frac{\cos^4 x\:dx}{(2\sin x\cos x+1)^4}
\\\\&=\frac14\int\frac{(1+\cos (2x))^2}{(\sin (2x)+1)^4}\:dx
\\\\&=2\int\frac{1+t^2}{(t+1)^8}\:dt.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: After that how to proceed

Comment: @user123733 You can proceed with $u=t+1$, $du=dt$, then you have to evaluate $\int\left(\frac1{u^8}+\frac{(u-1)^2}{u^8} \right)du$ Just expand.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{dx}{(2\sin x+\sec x)^4} $$
$$\int\frac{\sec^4 x}{(2\tan x + 1 + \tan^2 x)^4} $$
Put $\tan x +1 =t$
$$\int\frac{(t-1)^2 +1 }{t^8} $$